# Remove blue line above system bar

Tags: android, android-theme

A thin blue line (from Holo Theme I guess) appears between my application and the system bar, so basically above the system bar.

How do I hide it?

P.S. : I'm talking about the system bar (with Home and Back buttons) and NOT the action or status bar.

**EDIT**

This happens on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10'' with Android 4.0.3.

[image: Screenshot of the blue line]

Comment: Just for check, try implementing some other theme and check if that is still present.

Comment: @Geobits : But this is not present in any other app I've installed on this tablet.

Comment: Anybody any clue then?